# How to set the icon of cluster based on number of markers in osmdroid?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using clustering in osmdroid. Initially there is one big cluster. On zooming the cluster breaks in two separate clusters. Then on further zooming those clusters break in smaller clusters with less number of markers.

What i wanted was to have different icons for clusters based on the number of markers they have.

```
radiusMarkerClusterer.setRadius(40);
    radiusMarkerClusterer.setMaxClusteringZoomLevel(17);
    radiusMarkerClusterer.reversedClusters();



    for (int i = 0; i < alert.size(); i++) {
        position = new GeoPoint(Double.parseDouble(alert.get(i).getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(alert.get(i).getLongitude()));
        marker = new Marker(map);
        marker.setPosition(position);
        mapController.animateTo(position);
        Log.i(TAG, "MArker added to cluster ");

        radiusMarkerClusterer.add(marker);
    }
map.getOverlays().add(radiusMarkerClusterer);
```

This is how i am implementing clustering right now. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadiusMarkerClusterer does not support different drawables for different zooms. You'll need to create custom [MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/clustering/MarkerClusterer.java) subclass.

Check source of [RadiusMarkerClusterer](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/clustering/RadiusMarkerClusterer.java) for guidance and inspiration. A drawable for a marker is created in method buildClusterMarker

```
@Override public Marker buildClusterMarker(StaticCluster cluster, MapView mapView)
```

As you can see there is access to the MapView so you can obtain current zoom level and decide which icon should be used.

Comment: I figured that. And what you said was precisely what i did after a lot of research. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

create custom class RadiusMarkerClusterer.

```
      import android.content.Context;
        import android.graphics.*;
        import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
        import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
        import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.MotionEvent;
        import com.kintanpatel.mygmail.R;
        import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.clustering.MarkerClusterer;
        import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.clustering.StaticCluster;
        import org.osmdroid.util.BoundingBox;
        import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
        import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
        import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Iterator;
        import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * Radius-based Clustering algorithm:
 * create a cluster using the first point from the cloned list.
 * All points that are found within the neighborhood are added to this cluster.
 * Then all the neighbors and the main point are removed from the list of points.
 * It continues until the list is empty.
 * <p>
 * Largely inspired from GridMarkerClusterer by M.Kergall
 *
 * @author sidorovroman92@gmail.com
 */

public class RadiusMarkerClusterer extends MarkerClusterer {

    /**
     * cluster icon anchor
     */
    public float mAnchorU = Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, mAnchorV = Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER;
    /**
     * anchor point to draw the number of markers inside the cluster icon
     */
    public float mTextAnchorU = Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, mTextAnchorV = Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER;
    protected int mMaxClusteringZoomLevel = 17;
    protected int mRadiusInPixels = 100;
    protected double mRadiusInMeters;
    protected Paint mTextPaint;
    private ArrayList<Marker> mClonedMarkers;
    private Context mContext;

    public RadiusMarkerClusterer(Context ctx) {
        super();
        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(15 * ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        mTextPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Drawable clusterIconD = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(org.osmdroid.bonuspack.R.drawable.marker_cluster);
        Bitmap clusterIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) clusterIconD).getBitmap();
        setIcon(clusterIcon);
        mContext = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * If you want to change the default text paint (color, size, font)
     */
    public Paint getTextPaint() {
        return mTextPaint;
    }

    /**
     * Set the radius of clustering in pixels. Default is 100px.
     */
    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        mRadiusInPixels = radius;
    }

    /**
     * Set max zoom level with clustering. When zoom is higher or equal to this level, clustering is disabled.
     * You can put a high value to disable this feature.
     */
    public void setMaxClusteringZoomLevel(int zoom) {
        mMaxClusteringZoomLevel = zoom;
    }

    /**
     * Radius-Based clustering algorithm
     */
    @Override
    public ArrayList<org.osmdroid.bonuspack.clustering.StaticCluster> clusterer(MapView mapView) {

        ArrayList<org.osmdroid.bonuspack.clustering.StaticCluster> clusters = new ArrayList<org.osmdroid.bonuspack.clustering.StaticCluster>();
        convertRadiusToMeters(mapView);

        mClonedMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>(mItems); //shallow copy
        while (!mClonedMarkers.isEmpty()) {
            Marker m = mClonedMarkers.get(0);
            org.osmdroid.bonuspack.clustering.StaticCluster cluster = createCluster(m, mapView);
            clusters.add(cluster);
        }
        return clusters;
    }

    private org.osmdroid.bonuspack.clustering.StaticCluster createCluster(Marker m, MapView mapView) {
        GeoPoint clusterPosition = m.getPosition();

        org.osmdroid.bonuspack.clustering.StaticCluster cluster = new org.osmdroid.bonuspack.clustering.StaticCluster(clusterPosition);
        cluster.add(m);

        mClonedMarkers.remove(m);

        if (mapView.getZoomLevel() > mMaxClusteringZoomLevel) {
            //above max level => block clustering:
            return cluster;
        }

        Iterator<Marker> it = mClonedMarkers.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Marker neighbour = it.next();
            double distance = clusterPosition.distanceToAsDouble(neighbour.getPosition());
            if (distance <= mRadiusInMeters) {
                cluster.add(neighbour);
                it.remove();
            }
        }

        return cluster;
    }

    @Override
    public Marker buildClusterMarker(org.osmdroid.bonuspack.clustering.StaticCluster cluster, MapView mapView) {
        Marker m = new Marker(mapView);
        m.setPosition(cluster.getPosition());
        m.setInfoWindow(null);
        m.setAnchor(mAnchorU, mAnchorV);
        Log.e("cluster size", cluster.getSize() + "");

        int clusterSize = cluster.getSize();
        if (clusterSize < 1000 && clusterSize > 500) {
            Drawable clusterIconD = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.red_cluster, null);
            mClusterIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) Objects.requireNonNull(clusterIconD)).getBitmap();
        } else if (clusterSize > 50) {
            Drawable clusterIconD = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.red_cluster, null);
            mClusterIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) Objects.requireNonNull(clusterIconD)).getBitmap();
        } else {
            Drawable clusterIconD = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.cluster, null);
            mClusterIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) Objects.requireNonNull(clusterIconD)).getBitmap();
        }
        Bitmap finalIcon = Bitmap.createBitmap(mClusterIcon.getWidth(), mClusterIcon.getHeight(), mClusterIcon.getConfig());
        Canvas iconCanvas = new Canvas(finalIcon);
        iconCanvas.drawBitmap(mClusterIcon, 0, 0, null);
        String text = "" + cluster.getSize();
        int textHeight = (int) (mTextPaint.descent() + mTextPaint.ascent());
        iconCanvas.drawText(text,
                mTextAnchorU * finalIcon.getWidth(),
                mTextAnchorV * finalIcon.getHeight() - textHeight / 2,
                mTextPaint);
        m.setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(mapView.getContext().getResources(), finalIcon));
        // swapFunction(cluster.getSize());
        return m;
    }

    @Override
    public void renderer(ArrayList<org.osmdroid.bonuspack.clustering.StaticCluster> clusters, Canvas canvas, MapView mapView) {
        for (StaticCluster cluster : clusters) {
            if (cluster.getSize() == 1) {
                //cluster has only 1 marker => use it as it is:
                cluster.setMarker(cluster.getItem(0));
            } else {
                //only draw 1 Marker at Cluster center, displaying number of Markers contained
                Marker m = buildClusterMarker(cluster, mapView);
                cluster.setMarker(m);
            }
            Log.e("cluster size", cluster.getSize() + "");
        }


        //swapFunction(clusters, mapView);
    }

    private void convertRadiusToMeters(MapView mapView) {

        Rect mScreenRect = mapView.getIntrinsicScreenRect(null);

        int screenWidth = mScreenRect.right - mScreenRect.left;
        int screenHeight = mScreenRect.bottom - mScreenRect.top;

        BoundingBox bb = mapView.getBoundingBox();

        double diagonalInMeters = bb.getDiagonalLengthInMeters();
        double diagonalInPixels = Math.sqrt(screenWidth * screenWidth + screenHeight * screenHeight);
        double metersInPixel = diagonalInMeters / diagonalInPixels;

        mRadiusInMeters = mRadiusInPixels * metersInPixel;
    }

}
```

add below code in your map activity

```
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(20.5992, 72.9342);
       /* Drawable clusterIconD = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.cluster, null);
        Bitmap clusterIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) Objects.requireNonNull(clusterIconD)).getBitmap();*/
        RadiusMarkerClusterer poiMarkers = new RadiusMarkerClusterer(this, this);
        // poiMarkers.setIcon(clusterIcon);
        poiMarkers.mTextAnchorU = 0.50f;
        poiMarkers.mTextAnchorV = 0.50f;
        poiMarkers.getTextPaint().setTextSize(12 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        poiMarkers.mAnchorV = Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER;
        poiMarkers.setRadius(500);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(poiMarkers);
        for (LiveTrackingModel al : list) {
            Marker poiMarker = new Marker(mapView);
            poiMarker.setTitle(al.getVEHICLE_NUMBER());
            poiMarker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(Double.parseDouble(al.getLAT()), Double.parseDouble(al.getLON())));
            poiMarker.setIcon(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.compactor_running));
            poiMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);

           /* InfoWindow infoWindow = new MyInfoWindow(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble, mMapView);
            startMarker.setInfoWindow(infoWindow);*/
            //poiMarker.setInfoWindow();
            //poiMarker.setRelatedObject(poi);
            poiMarkers.add(poiMarker);
        }
        poiMarkers.buildClusterMarker(new StaticCluster(startPoint), mapView);
        poiMarkers.clusterer(mapView);
```